# How to solve this limit? (2)

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

How to solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x}$$

Comment: I don't think you need l'Hôpital. Have you tried plugging in $x=0$? What happens to the numerator, what about the denominator?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout $\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: That's right. Does it tend towards $+\infty$, or $-\infty$, or neither?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout + infinity

Comment: Are you sure about that? Check the case where $x<0$. Note that if $|x|<1$, then $x^2<|x|$.

Comment: Well, does $\lim_{x\to 0}$ mean $x  > 0$ or $x < 0$?

Comment: @fleablood $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ is only defined when $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)$, in which case all three are equal.

Comment: which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

There is no need to use l'Hôpital, since your limit is on the form $\frac{1}{0}$ (and not $\frac{0}{0}$ nor $\frac{\pm\infty}{\infty}$), which either becomes $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ (or neither). Look at limit from two different cases, one where $x>0$ and the other where $x<0$, that is, find:

- $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\ 0^+}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x}\tag{1}$$
- $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\ 0^-}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x}\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

On simplification

$$\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x}\\ = \lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}{x(x-1)^2}\\ = \lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{x^3-1}{x(x-1)^2}\\ = \lim_{x\to\ 0} \left(\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}- \frac{1}{x(x-1)^2}\right)\\= 0-\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{1}{x(x-1)^2}\\=-\lim_{x\to\ 0} \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x-2}{(x-1)^2}\right)\\\ =-2-\lim_{x\to\ 0}\frac{1}{x}$$

I'm guessing you can make your deductions now

Answer (score -1):

$\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x}=$

$\lim_{x\to\ 0} \frac{(x^2-x)+(2x+1)}{x^2-x}=$

$\lim_{x\to\ 0} 1 + \frac{2x+1}{x^2-x}=$

$1 + \lim_{x\to\ 0} (\frac {2x}{x^2 - x} + \frac 1{x^2 - x})=$

$1 + \lim_{x\to\ 0} (\frac {2}{x-1} + \frac 1{x^2 - x})=$

$1 - 2 + \lim_{x\to\ 0}\frac 1{x^2 -x}$

$-1 + \lim_{x\to\ 0}\frac 1{x(x-1)}$

If $x < 0$ then $x, x-1 < 0$ and this diverges to positive infinity.  If $x > 0$ then $x > 0; x-1 < 0$ and this diverges to negative infinity.  So there is no reasonable limit.